# Calculating the scale between 2 sets of numbers to work out a servo point

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, raspberry-pi

I am trying to work out the position I should make a servo based on the axis of my Ps4 Controller

This is the scale I have on the servo:

Left - 0.1, Center - 6, Right - 8

On the Controller

Left = -32767, Center = 0, Right = 32767

So what I need it to so is for example if the number is 11000 then it is going to be turning right but it will need to be a number between 6 and 8 to the same scale that 11000 is between 0 and 32767.

What is the best way to create a function to calculate this so I can convert the axis into a servo position on the fly?

Comment: what is the resolution of your servo?  It seems the controller has roughly 2**16 positions it can use

Comment: why is your servo asymetric? left to center is -5.9, center to right is -2